# Div on top of carousel

Tags: html, css, layout, bootstrap-4

I am trying to build the following layout with bootstrap 4, I would like a div on top of the carousel on full screen I would like it to pull to the left, mid size screens in the center and on mobile screen size I want it to sit below the carousel, like in my picture below:

[image: ![image]

So far I've tried to put it inside columns but as you can see in my code the column doesn't sit at the same width as the content below and whatever I tried it would either make the carousel item smaller or it just didn't work.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KQvJQp

```css
#mu-carousel .carousel-item {
  max-height: 540px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#mu-carousel .carousel-box {
  background: #333333;
  text-align: left;
}

#mu-promo {
  background: #eeeeee;
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<header id="mu-carousel" class="">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/312105/pexels-photo-312105.jpeg" alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block offset-1 col-lg-3  carousel-box">
          <h3>TITLEH3</h3>

          <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Call to action</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/312105/pexels-photo-312105.jpeg" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block offset-1 col-lg-3 carousel-box">
          <h3>TITLEH3</h3>

          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Call to action</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>

<section id="mu-promo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        lorem ipsum
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: By "on top of carousel" you mean hovering over the carousel and thus overlaying it? Is that what you mean?

Comment: In the first 2 cases yes in the third i want it under the carousel (or rather split the div the carousel and the box are in and put carousel (50% topside) and the box (50% bottom). Right now the box sits there at the wrong position but also disapears when you scale down.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your carousel is the div#carouselExampleIndicators then set the header#mu-carousel CSS position to relative and in the header#mu-carousel add another div with position absolute that will hold the div that you want on top of the carousel

```
<header id="mu-carousel" class="">
   <div id="carouselExampleIndicators">carousel</div>
   <div>div (with position absolute) that floats on top of carousel</div>
</header>
```